# unix curl meaning of checkmarks

Tags: curl, embedded-linux, command-line-arguments

Hello people i have a question about how the 'curl' parser works in a linux commandline:

i work on a jokto-linux-system where i write commandline instructions:

I want to know what is the difference of with checkmarks '...' and without those.

commandline with checkmarks:

curl 'http://localhost:80/uri/?$sortby=name' > data.json

commandline without checkmarks:

curl -i http://localhost:80/uri/?$sortby=name > data.json

The command with the checkmarks bring me back a http 200OK and a sorted response in json format. the other command without checkmarks brings me too 200OK but the response is unsorted.
I dont know the reason why.

Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, those are called *single quotes*, not checkmarks. This is a checkmark: ✓

Bash understands single quotes as protecting text of an argument against interpretation. Typically, nothing that is single-quoted will have a special meaning, and will be interpreted just as plain text.

Without them, `?` and `$` have special meaning to bash: `?` participates in "globbing" (expanding filenames to match patterns, where `?` is a placeholder for a single character), and `$` participates in variable expansion (`$sortby` will get replaced by the value of the variable `sortby`).

`?` might not match anything and so will be left alone, but `$sortby`, as the variable is likely is not defined, will get replaced by empty string. The end result is that before `curl` sees the argument, it will be transformed if unquoted, most likely becoming `http://localhost:80/uri/?=name` - not what you want.

There are some more characters that would mess up your command line even more if they were present; for example, `!`, `&`, parentheses and more. It is a good idea always to quote your URI.

Answer (score 0):

A checkmark (`✓`) has no special meaning in shell.

A string quoted with single quote marks (`'`) with stop characters with special meaning having that meaning (e.g. `&` won't put the script in the background and `$` won't start a variable).

Further reading:

- [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)
- [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the correct answer. Sorry for that but my googletranslator tranlate me from german="Häckchen" to english="checkmarks" and not to quotes. But normaly i know this word.